# How do I derive the following expression for the sum of orthogonal matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, orthogonal-matrices, vector-auto-regression

In Johansen's book 'Likelihood-based inference in cointegrated vector autoregressive models', in order to get the expression for the Granger's representation theorem he claims that:

$$\beta_\bot(\alpha'_\bot \beta_\bot )^{-1} \alpha'_\bot + \alpha (\beta' \alpha)^{-1} \beta'  = I \tag{1}$$

Where:

$\alpha$ is $N\times R$, $\text{rank}(\alpha) =R$

$\beta$ is $N\times R$, $\text{rank}(\beta) =R$

$\beta_\bot $ is $N\times (N-R)$, $\text{rank}(\beta_\bot) =N-R$

$\alpha_\bot $ is $N\times (N-R)$, $\text{rank}(\alpha_\bot) =N-R$

$\alpha' \alpha_\bot =0$

$\beta' \beta_\bot =0$

I am not able to prove (1). Can you help me, please?

Comment: Hint: Use the fact that $(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1} A^{-1}$, where $A$ and $B$ are matrices with the appropriate dimensions.

Comment: Thank you. But in order to use the fact you mentioned, A and B should be both invertible, but it looks like they are not. Moreover, even if they were, the sum of the two components should be I+I, shouldn't it? Thank you.

Comment: Good point; I hadn’t read your question carefully. Let me get back to you if I think of something else.

Comment: For sake of clarity, Johansen denotes by $A'$ the transpose of matrix $A$ whereas it's more common in linear algebra to write $A^\top$ or $A^t$.

Comment: The derivation of this formula in the case of $\beta'\alpha$ having full rank is exercise 3.7 in Johansen.

Comment: @Semiclassical thank you, I have just noticed it. However, I am still not able to get the result

Comment: I'm noticing something weird: The assumptions provided do not guarantee that $\alpha'_\bot \beta_\top$ and $\beta' \alpha$ are non-singular. (Consider a case where $R=N-1$ and $\alpha_\top,\beta_\top=0$ are orthogonal vectors.) So it seems there's some extra premises being assumed by Johansen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stated identity need not be valid under the assumptions provided. Consider for example $\alpha=\beta_{\bot}=\binom{1}{0}$ and $\beta=\alpha_{\bot}=\binom{0}{1}$ corresponding to $N=2$, $R=1$. These vectors all have rank $R=N-R=1$, and they satisfy $\alpha'\alpha_\bot = \beta'\beta_\bot = 0$. But $\alpha'_\bot \beta_\bot=\beta'\alpha=0$, so  $(\alpha'_\bot \beta_\bot)^{-1}$, $(\beta'\alpha)^{-1}$ do not exist.

The identity is true, however, if we may assume that the 2-by-1 block matrices $(\alpha,\beta_\bot)$, $(\beta,\alpha_\bot)$ are nonsingular. In that case we have the following derivation:
\begin{align}
I
&=\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta_\bot \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta_\bot \end{pmatrix}^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} \beta' \\ \alpha_\bot' \end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix} \beta' \\ \alpha_\bot' \end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta_\bot \end{pmatrix}
\left[\begin{pmatrix} \beta' \\ \alpha_\bot' \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta_\bot \end{pmatrix}  \right]^{-1}\begin{pmatrix} \beta' \\ \alpha_\bot' \end{pmatrix}\\
&= \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta_\bot \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} \beta'\alpha & \beta'\beta_\bot \\ \alpha_\bot'\alpha & \alpha'_\bot \beta_\bot \end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix} \beta' \\ \alpha_\bot' \end{pmatrix}\\
&= \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta_\bot \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} \beta'\alpha & 0 \\ 0 & \alpha'_\bot \beta_\bot \end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix} \beta' \\ \alpha_\bot' \end{pmatrix}\\
&= \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta_\bot \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} (\beta'\alpha)^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & (\alpha'_\bot \beta_\bot)^{-1} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \beta' \\ \alpha_\bot' \end{pmatrix}\\
&= \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta_\bot \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} (\beta'\alpha)^{-1}\beta' \\ (\alpha'_\bot \beta_\bot)^{-1}\alpha_\bot' \end{pmatrix}\\
&=\alpha(\beta'\alpha)^{-1}\beta' + \beta_\bot(\alpha'_\bot \beta_\bot)^{-1}\alpha_\bot'.
\end{align}
Thus the identity follows algebraically if we grant that the above block-matrix inverses exist. It may be possible to weaken the premises further.

Comment: Looking into some of the literature, it seems that one typically assumes (1) $\alpha'\beta$ has rank $R$ (which is as large as could be given that $\alpha,\beta$ are $N\times R$), (2) $\alpha_\bot'\beta_\bot$ has full rank (so rank $N-R$). My counterexample satisfies neither premise, so it seems plausible that these would be enough to justify the identity.

Comment: Thank you. Very much appreciated.

Comment: @alchemy I’m still working to finish this answer (see the edit I rolled back if you want to see the extent of it)

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you can just plugin $\beta_{\perp}$ on both sides of the equation to see that the transformation on the lhs - abbreviated by $A$ - gives $A\beta_{\perp}=\beta_{\perp}$. Likewise, plugging in $\alpha$ on both sides leads to $A\alpha = \alpha$. So the lhs acts as an identity on all the column vectors of the matrix $(\beta_{\perp}, \alpha)$. Hence, if we add the assumption that  $(\beta_{\perp}, \alpha)$ is nonsingular, then the lhs acts as the identity for all vectors of a given basis and hence for all vectors.